# Calculating water pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, flow

We've built a waterwheel to use in a small stream and are trying to calculate it's efficiency. The Hydropower equation goes as: KiloWatts = P * Q / 600, P being pressure in bars and Q being flow in litres per minute. We estimate Q to be 120.

How can we guess or calculate P?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step backwards to clarify where the hydropower equation comes from.

Power is always the product of an effort variable (pressure, in this case) and a flow variable (volume per second), being certain to make the units consistent throughout. So let's look at the situation of a tank full of water on top of a tower. A pipe leads out of the bottom of the tank to a valve which is open at ground level, and water is shooting out of the open valve at high speed. The theoretical *power* of that jet of water is the hydrostatic pressure which you would measure at ground level inside the pipe with the valve shut, times the rate at which the water is leaving the pipe with the valve open.

Your problem arises when the source pressure is not only low but hard to measure, as is the case when you place a water wheel into a moving stream of water (which pressure do you measure? where do you measure it?).

In this case you have to use a more complicated way of determining the power content of the flowing water which looks at *momentum transfer* between the moving water and the wheel blades and expresses efficiency in terms of kinetic energy delivery from the parcels of flowing water to the rotating wheel.

This is a solved problem- look up *stream water wheels* for the derivation.